# I'm having difficulty installing apache superset in docker on Raspberry Pi - does anyone have some simple instructions to build from source?

Tags: apache-superset

Can anyone help with some instructions please?

I was hoping that docker-compose up would somehow magically rebuild from source using the right aarch64 (arm) architecture but it seems not. Some containers (eg superset-websocket) start ok but most of the other containers fail with
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

What's the simplest way to build the required container image(s) from source please?

Thanks for any pointers...

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I'm afraid not. This was the only place I asked. I ended up going in a completely different direction.